# In $\triangle ABC$, prove $4\left(\,bc \cos^2 \frac{A}2 + ca \cos^2 \frac{B}{2} + ab \cos^2 \frac{C}{2}\,\right) = (a + b + c)^2$

Tags: trigonometry

> In any $\triangle ABC$, with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ opposite respective angles $A$, $B$, $C$, prove that:
>   $$4\left(\,bc \cos^2\frac{A}{2} + ca \cos^2 \frac{B}{2} + ab \cos^2 \frac{C}{2}\,\right) = (a + b + c)^2$$

I am currently in class 11th and I am having trouble solving this. I know this is not a homework solving website, but I have no other option. Sorry. I will never again post a homework question.

Comment: Please change the title to something more meaningful. Also use MathJax wherever possible. And of course, welcome to Math.SE. You should show some effort on homework questions, and someone will gladly help

Comment: furthermore define your variables

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: You are allowed to post homework questions. However, we just ask that you also show your thoughts on the problem. This may include a partial solutions or anything you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$2\cos^2 \theta-1 =\cos 2\theta,$$L.H.S becomes:

$$2(bc(1+\cos A)+ca(1+\cos B)+ab(1+\cos C))=$$
$$2(bc+ca+ab)+2(bc\cos A +ca\cos B+ab\cos C)$$
Now use the cosine law
$$\cos A= \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} ,\cos B=\cdots$$ to get
$$2(bc+ca+ab)+(a^2+b^2+c^2)=$$
$$(a+b+c)^2$$